# Reduced audio quality on Bluetooth headset during calls in comparison to mac OS

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I have just switched from MacBook Pro to a laptop running (k)ubuntu 20.04.

When using my Bluetooth headset for the A2DP profile the music sounds excellent, unfortunately for the HSP/HFP profile the quality for both played and recorded sounds drastically drops, so that even my colleagues from the calls can experience this.

I know, that the HSP/HFP profiles cause the quality drop, but while running the same headset on MBP I wasn't able to observe that big issues.

What it might be caused by? Could it be some Bluetooth adapter issue, or rather driver-related? Am I missing some other Bluetooth profile dedicated to videocalls? Is it possible to improve the HSP/HFP audio quality on ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out that this is a missing feature/bug in `pulseaudio`. See this ticket for more details: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1838151

For now there is nothing left to do except for waiting for an update (or supporting the developer in their effort).

Comment: Yes, this is outrageous. I just found out about it.

- A workaround is to buy a bluetooth USB chip, which will be recognized by the pc as a proper sound card. 
- A solution is to switch to pipewire, which implements the right codecs.